# Redis performance if number of keys are increasing

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

We have a Redis Database that currently contains more than 10 Million keys in Production environment and as per our prediction it might grow to more than 100-200 Million keys.

Will it impact my Read/Write time to Redis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think raising of keys count will not impact the benchmark of Redis, but the write/read rate is limited to your *Resources* and you can't expect Redis to response you more than potential of resources. **So if you try to read/write more, it may result to delay, connection lost or ...**

> My suggestion is to use Redis cluster(with multiple servers) to increase the read/write rate.

Comment: We have enough memory to store more than 100-200 Million keys as per our calculations. However, the only concern here is that whether the performance degrades over read and write when the number of keys increases.

Comment: There is more effective parameters besides of memory capacity.